# I am getting error while installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. When I try to install the latest version of Rails, I get the following error. Could you guys help me out?

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/stephensamkinston/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0-dev/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.0.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
    - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch
    - 0003-Stop-parsing-on-entities-boundaries-errors.patch
    - 0004-Cleanup-conditional-section-error-handling.patch
    - 0005-CVE-2015-1819-Enforce-the-reader-to-run-in-constant-.patch
    - 0006-Another-variation-of-overflow-in-Conditional-section.patch
    - 0007-Fix-an-error-in-previous-Conditional-section-patch.patch
    - 0008-CVE-2015-8035-Fix-XZ-compression-support-loop.patch
    - 0009-Updated-config.guess.patch
    - 0010-Fix-parsering-short-unclosed-comment-uninitialized-access.patch
    - 0011-Avoid-extra-processing-of-MarkupDecl-when-EOF.patch
    - 0012-Avoid-processing-entities-after-encoding-conversion-.patch
    - 0013-CVE-2015-7497-Avoid-an-heap-buffer-overflow-in-xmlDi.patch
    - 0014-CVE-2015-5312-Another-entity-expansion-issue.patch
    - 0015-Add-xmlHaltParser-to-stop-the-parser.patch
    - 0016-Detect-incoherency-on-GROW.patch
    - 0017-CVE-2015-7500-Fix-memory-access-error-due-to-incorre.patch
    - 0018-CVE-2015-8242-Buffer-overead-with-HTML-parser-in-pus.patch
    - 0019-Do-not-print-error-context-when-there-is-none.patch
    - 0020-xmlStopParser-reset-errNo.patch
    - 0021-Reuse-xmlHaltParser-where-it-makes-sense.patch
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you dont have the build tools installed

Install build toosl by running the following commands

1) `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

2) `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Now instal rails

3) `gem install rails`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: mac OSX yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: getting different error..this time when followed the tutorial

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/stephensamkinston/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160214-93801-1k2jxbs.rb extconf.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103430/discussion-between-ramesh-kumar-thiyagarajan-and-user578386).